# Shared element transition - number of views

Tags: android, android-transitions, shared-element-transition, fragment-transitions

Does a shared element transition from one view to another need to contain the same amount of child views? My experience is that the following crash appears if this is not the case:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransitionImpl.setNameOverridesReordered(FragmentTransitionImpl.java:182)
        at androidx.fragment.app.DefaultSpecialEffectsController.startTransitions(DefaultSpecialEffectsController.java:665)
        at androidx.fragment.app.DefaultSpecialEffectsController.executeOperations(DefaultSpecialEffectsController.java:114)
        at androidx.fragment.app.SpecialEffectsController.executePendingOperations(SpecialEffectsController.java:294)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$3.run(Fragment.java:2776)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Adding empty views usually resolves the issue. I could not find anything in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/animate#shared) about this, hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The views do **not** need to contain the same amount of child views.

This was a bug in Fragment version `1.3.4` and it is fixed now.

Adding a dependency on `androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.0-alpha03` resolved the issue.

The [release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.4.0-alpha03) states the following:

> From Fragment 1.3.5: Fixed a regression in shared element transitions introduced in Fragment 1.3.4 by aosp/1679887. Fragments now correctly handle transition groups (either set directly via transitionGroup="true" or indirectly via a transitionName or background) and shared elements will no longer throw IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions. (I16484, b/188679569, b/188969304)